# How do I resolve "Uncaught TypeError: iterable.hasOwnProperty is not a function"?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, babeljs, react-leaflet

I am trying to use the `react-leaflet-markerclusters` package in my code. However after installing it and running `npm start`, I am getting this error (

```
loadMessages.js?4a62:4 Uncaught TypeError: iterable.hasOwnProperty is not a function
    at traverse (loadMessages.js?4a62:4:1)
    at loadMessages (loadMessages.js?4a62:25:1)
    at eval (Root.js?e933:41:13)
    at Module../src/masterApp/components/app/Root.js (bundle.js:49970:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:790:30)
    at fn (bundle.js:101:20)
    at eval (index.js?b635:1:1)
    at Module../src/index.js (bundle.js:49802:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:790:30)
    at fn (bundle.js:101:20)
```

) and a white screen.

I did a global search in my application for `hasOwnProperty` and there are no results. I'm assuming this is tied to an external package. After further digging, it seems like it is tied to my `loadMessages` import in `Root.js`.

Here's a snippet of `Root.js`:

```
import "core-js/stable";
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
import React from "react";
...
import { loadMessages, LocalizationProvider } from "@progress/kendo-react-intl";
import messages from "../../../assets/messages/messages";

loadMessages(messages.ar, "ar");
loadMessages(messages.en, "en");
loadMessages(messages.es, "es");
loadMessages(messages.fr, "fr");
```

I've tried updating `@progress/kendo-react-intl` to the latest version but I still get the TypeError. Do I need a prefix in front of loadMessages?

If it helps any, please note that I am using node 14.4.0 and babel 7. Updating node beyond this version causes a node-sass error. Should I downgrade babel?

Comment: It maybe comes from your arguments message.ar messages.en etc. Some of these may return null or undefined where the lib expects an object on which it can call hasOwnProperty.

Comment: I was able to `console.log` the objects and they're not null or undefined. So something else must be wrong. Here's a sample of what "messages.en" returns: `{"Account":"Account","Add.device.group":"Add Device Group", ...}`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change:

```
loadMessages(messages.ar, "ar");
loadMessages(messages.en, "en");
loadMessages(messages.es, "es");
loadMessages(messages.fr, "fr");
```

To be:

```
loadMessages(JSON.stringify(messages.ar), "ar");
loadMessages(JSON.stringify(messages.en), "en");
loadMessages(JSON.stringify(messages.es), "es");
loadMessages(JSON.stringify(messages.fr), "fr");
```